# How to return x nearest people in flutter with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, geolocation

Is it possible to query a certain number of nearest locations from a cloud firestore database in Flutter? The [geoflutterfire](https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire) package only appears to allow you to query locations within a radius. Is the only solution to slowly increase the radius until an acceptable number of users is found? This sounds like a very unclean solution. Are there other packages or methods that will give you this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the nature of how the Geo*Fire packages work, they cannot return the X nearest results.

The common pattern:

1. Start with a reasonable range, client-side order the results on distance, and then return the top X.
2. If you got too few results, try again with a larger range.

Increasing the range is not as expensive in Firestore as you may think, as the documents for the smaller range will already be in the client-side cache after the first geoquery.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I asked because the package does not support the use of the .limit() function, so I'm concerned that I may receive too many results and be charged for too many reads. I will slowly increase the radius to combat this. Thanks.

Comment: You are almost guaranteed to overread, because these packages all work based on geohashes, which only cover rectangular ranges, while a point and radius make a circle. If you're worried about cost, consider using the Realtime Database. While it has the same problem, the cost for such small read operations is usually a lot smaller.